# Angular js unable to assign scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, electron

I am using electron.js and I have a custom node.js module that uses the fs module to search for a word in a file.

I am using angular.js to save the result of the file search in $scope but the scope value always returns undefined.

Here is the angular code:

```
searchApp.controller("userWordController", function(GetSearchService) {
   $scope.getDefinition = function(){
      GetSearchService.findWord()
      .searchWord('apple', function(arr){
        console.log('this line of code never gets executed');
       $scope.wordsResult = arr;
     });
   }
});
```

It does not return the arr variable.

Here is all the related bits to the code:

node.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');

var reader = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('testfile.txt'),
});


var word = function DefineWord() {
    this.reader = reader;
}
var search = defineWord.prototype.searchWord = function(search, cb) {
    var arr = [];
    this.reader.on('line', function(line) {

        if (line.search(searchTerm) !== -1) {
            arr.push(line);
        }
    });

    this.reader.on('close', function() {
        cb(arr)
    })

}

exports.word = word;
```

angular.js:

```
var searchApp = angular.module("searchApp", []);
var searchMod = require("./search");

searchApp.controller("userWordController", function($scope, GetSearchService) {
    $scope.getDefinition = function() {
        GetSearchService.findWord()
            .searchWord('apple', function(arr) {
              console.log('this line of code never gets executed');
              $scope.wordsResult = arr;
            });
    }
});

searchApp.service('GetSearchService', function() {
    this.findWord = function() {
        return new searchMod.word;
    }
})
```

html

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"> </script>
 <script src = "app.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div ng-app="searchApp" ng-controller="userWordController">
      <button ng-click="getDefinition()"> click here</button>
      <p>{{wordsResult}}</p>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure "this.reader.on('close'..." actually happens?

Comment: it works when you run it from node. Also works inside the angular controller Only does not work when it is called inside `$scope.getDefinition`. The bit i have added the `console.log` code.

Comment: Are you saying it works inside the controller...but not from $scope.getDefinition? Can you include code to show that? And check that $scope.getDefinition is definitely being called?

Comment: added the html also. getDefinition gets called by way of ng-click. If i run the code outside of getdefinition in the controller it runs fine.

Comment: In that case I'm stuck, sorry. It seems like it should work, so perhaps this is an issue with electron.js?